# How to append rows to CSV data?

Tags: python, csv, append

This is a sample of a code part of a larger scraper. The .csv file created with this code contains only one row. I can't figure out how to append correctly every data that I've scraped.

```
csv_file = open('D:\Documents\Oeil\pole_emploi\jobs3.csv', 'w', newline='')
csv_writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
csv_writer.writerow(['titre', 'contrat', 'localisation', 'description'])

driver.get('https://candidat.pole-emploi.fr/offres/emploi/horticulteur/s1m1')
# Click cookies popup
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT,"Continuer sans accepter"))).click()
time.sleep(3)

# Get the elements
try:
    zone = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
       EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "zone-resultats"))
       )
    offres = zone.find_elements_by_css_selector("div.media-body")
    offres2 = zone.find_elements_by_css_selector("div.media-right.media-middle.hidden-xs")
    for offre in offres:
       titre = (offre.find_element_by_css_selector("h2.t4.media-heading")).text
       print(titre)
       localisation = (offre.find_element_by_css_selector("span")).text
       print(localisation)
       description =(offre.find_element_by_class_name("description")).text
       print(description)
       
    for offre2 in offres2:
       contrat = (offre2.find_element_by_class_name("contrat")).text
       print(contrat)
    csv_writer.writerow([titre, contrat, localisation, description])
except Exception as ex:
    print(ex)
finally:
     csv_file.close()
     driver.quit()
```

Comment: A DataFrame is something else entirely. I've edited your title.

Comment: Do you know for certain that there is no exception being generated? If there was one it would prevent the subsequent rows from being appended. Because there doesn't appear to be anything wrong with how you're writing CSV rows.

Comment: Yes I'm certain, but the resulting CSV is only made of one row, corresponding to the last bit of scraped data. Actually, this code is nested in a 'try except' and even a larger scraper but I've only shown this bit as I thought it was clearer for the problem I'm exposing here

Comment: Well, it's tough to know without seeing what else is surrounding this but I get that there's a balance with not showing a several-hundred line program. This kind of thing could happen if there's a loop, and you're opening the file every time through the loop. You would need to put the `open()` outside / just before the loop body.

Comment: Thanks, I will first investigate what you've said and I will also add more lines in my post so you can see the surroundings.

Comment: Oh, so now I've seen the HTML on the page. The problem is the opposite of what I thought: you're looping over many elements in the page, but only writing to the CSV at then end of all of those loops. If you can't put the CSV writing code into one of those loops, you'd need to build up a list of all your scraped information and then write it to the CSV using `csv_writer.writerows(built_up_list)`.